# What's wrong with this for/if loop? (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

There are two columns.
In a new column, I want it to *randomly* add or subtract the other two columns:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data) {
  if (round(runif(1, 1,2),0) == 1) {
    data$p_p2= data$p[i] + data$p2[i]
} else {
  data$p_p2  = data$p[i] - data$p2[i]
}
}
```

e.g.,

```
  p  p1  p_p2 *goal*

  1  3   -2
  3  3   6
  5  2   7
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `ifelse` instead of for loop i.e. `with(data, ifelse(round(runif(nrow(data),1,2),0)==1, p+p1, p-p1))`  In your `for` loop, some parentheses are missing and you may need`[i]`

Comment: I think this version may work for you `data$p_p2 <- NA;for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (round(runif(1, 1,2),0) == 1) {
    data$p_p2[i]= data$p[i] + data$p1[i]
} else {
  data$p_p2[i]  = data$p[i] - data$p1[i]
}
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `ifelse`

```
 data$p_p2 <- with(data, ifelse(round(runif(nrow(data),1,2),0)==1,
                p+p1, p-p1))
```

Or modify your code

```
data$p_p2 <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
      if (round(runif(1, 1,2),0) == 1) {
        data$p_p2[i]= data$p[i] + data$p1[i] }
         else { 
        data$p_p2[i] = data$p[i] - data$p1[i]
    }
 }
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(p = c(1, 3, 5), p1 = c(3, 3, 2), p_p2 = c(NA, 
 NA, NA)), .Names = c("p", "p1", "p_p2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop is not necessary for this type of problem. It's good practice to think about logic as a "new variable" because it tends to make things easier to work with.

```
set.seed(42) # for reproducibility
dat <- as.data.frame( # dat because data is a command, don't overwrite it
    matrix(round(runif(100,1,10), nrow = 50, ncol = 2)) # example data
)

# Random response to question: Should be added? TRUE/FALSE
dat$Test <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),50,replace = TRUE) 
# IF TRUE, ADD, ELSE, SUBTRACT
dat$Result <- ifelse(dat$Test, dat$V1 + dat$V2, dat$V1 - dat$V2)
```